# Nested Master Pages - changes ids

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have added a nested master page...but it has changed the id of many parts of my code. I have the same id in my master page and child master page at the moment.

The ids for each element have now added the master page id to the id of the element.

For instance, I used to reference as such

```
var lat = $("#cphBody_hidLat").val();
```

Now I need to reference it as

```
var lat = $("#cphBody_cphBody_hidLat").val();
```

I don't want to make changes all over my code...is there a way to not need the full "path" to reference the values?

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what necessitated the addition of a nested master page?

Comment: The site needed to be white labeled